# Replace method isEqualToString with a method like containsString: for a UITextField response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in my app and based on the user's input I want it to push to a specific view controller. right now my code is simply:

```
 if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@"tall"]) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yesViewController animated:YES];
}
```

however only if the user types in exactly "tall" it will work. I want to make it so that if he types "Jim is tall" is still performs the action. Basically I'm looking for a replacement for the method `isEqualToString:` and change it into `containsString:` which I can't seem to find. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Use `rangeOfString:`:

```
if ([self.textField.text rangeOfString:@"tall"].location != NSNotFound) {
    // the text contains "tall"
}
```

Use `rangeOfString:options:` if you want to ignore case or other options:

```
if ([self.textField.text rangeOfString:@"tall" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
    // the text contains "tall"
}
```